# SpriteKit joint physics changing physics body

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I am working with the joint method in spritekit, but once I join two sprites it seems to change the physics bodies. I have two rectangles joined at a corner and when they fold, I would expect the blue rectangle to sit on top of the white triangle, but this is the result. How do I maintain their physics bodies, so they don't overlap?
[image]
[image]

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

let character = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.whiteColor(), size: CGSizeMake(150, 30))
let character2 = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.blueColor(), size: CGSizeMake(150, 30))
let character3 = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.greenColor(), size: CGSizeMake(50, 300))

 let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds


override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

  //  let scene = GameScene(size: SKView.frame)


    let borderBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
    borderBody.friction = 5
    self.physicsBody = borderBody

    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0, -1.0)

    character.position = CGPointMake(550, 400)
    character2.position = CGPointMake(400, 400)
    character3.position = CGPointMake(400, 100)

    character.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: character.size)
    character2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: character2.size)
    character3.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: character3.size)

    self.character.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
    self.character2.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
    self.character3.physicsBody!.dynamic = true

    self.addChild(character)
    self.addChild(character2)
    self.addChild(character3)

    var myJoint = SKPhysicsJointPin.jointWithBodyA(character2.physicsBody, bodyB: character.physicsBody, anchor: CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMaxX(self.character2.frame), y: CGRectGetMinY(self.character.frame)))

   self.physicsWorld.addJoint(myJoint)

    var myJoint2 = SKPhysicsJointPin.jointWithBodyA(character2.physicsBody, bodyB: character.physicsBody, anchor: CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMaxX(self.character2.frame), y: CGRectGetMaxY(self.character.frame)))
    //self.physicsWorld.addJoint(myJoint2)

}
```

Comment: You should set `physicsBody`'s `categoryBitMask` and `collisionBitMask` as well.

Comment: read categoryBitMask and collisionBitMask  in sprite kit collisionBitMask stop two object for overlapping

Comment: Thank you for the replies! I will try that tonight